# Add a Semicolon Automatically in C With a Vim Plugin

Tags: filetype-c, plugin

I am a C programmer and I am looking for a plugin that automatically adds semicolons when necessary before writing changes to a file.
For example, look at the following example.

```c
printf("%s\n", string)
```

This should be turned into:

```c
printf("%s\n", string);
```

It would be nice if the same plugin also did this for other languages that require semicolons, like CSS.

Comment: Maybe with treesitter it's possible. Otherwise with regex-style substitution, it'd be a hell to come up with the correct regex for a C-style statement. (My unprofessional advice is to just put the semicolon yourself.)

Comment: Okay thanks :).

Comment: This is not directly related to the question, but, one can quickly add a semicolon to the end of the current line with the keys `A ; Esc`... and repeat this at another line with `.`.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. Your request is valid. It's just that as far as I understand, the solution would be *very* complicated (as illustrated below by Martin). The cost-benefit ratio just wouldn't be feasible.

Answer (score 3):

Languages with automatic semicolon insertion such as JavaScript and Go have as bunch of edge-cases where they do unexpected things, and any C solution will probably be no different. In C macros in particular make it extra hard:

```
#define IF    if(
#define THEN  ){
#define ELSE  } else {
#define ELIF  } else if (
#define FI    ;}

IF foo THEN
   stmt();
FI
```

This is a bit of a silly thing to do, [but people do use macros like that](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/mac.h). I've seen "macro abuse" like this in more modern/current codebases too.

Merely inserting a semi-colon after a `)\n` won't really work either:

```
int value = (cond == 5)
    ? (this_value)
    : (other_value);

if (foo)
{
}

if (foo) bar();  // Do need it here!
```

So you really need deep knowledge of the C code, and as mentioned, even with that it's pretty tricky to get right. There's an [open feature request for clangd](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/842) language server.

For CSS it might be a little bit more doable as the syntax is simpler, but I wouldn't be surprised if there are edge cases there too.

My advice: just type the semicolons.